# onDetailUser() делает переход на страницу detail, данные отображаются. Если выполнить перезагрузку на странице detail, данные текущего user теряются?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

home.component.ts

```
public onDetailUser(id: number): void {
   this.router.navigate(['description', id]);
};
```

detail.component.ts

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchUserDetail();
  };

private fetchUserDetail(): Observable<UserDTO> {
    this.userDetails$ = this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
      map((params: Params) =>  {
        this.userId = Number(params['id']); 
        this.store.dispatch(userActions.LoadUserRequest({ userId: this.userId }));
        return this.userId;
      }),
      switchMap(() => this.store.select(userSelectors.getUserSelector(this.userId))),
      tap(user => console.log(user)),
    )
    return this.userDetails$;
  };
```

user.actions.ts

```
import { createAction, props, union } from "@ngrx/store";

import { UserDTO } from "../../interfaces/user.interface";

export enum UsersActionsType {
    ...
    LOAD_USER_REQUEST = '[USER] Load User Request',
    LOAD_USER_SUCCESS = '[USER] Load User Success',
    LOAD_USER_FAIL = '[USER] Load User Fail',
    ...
};

...
export const LoadUserRequest = createAction (
    UsersActionsType.LOAD_USER_REQUEST,
    props<{userId: number}>(),
);

export const LoadUserSuccess = createAction (
    UsersActionsType.LOAD_USER_SUCCESS,
    props<{user: UserDTO}>(),
);

export const LoadUserFail = createAction (
    UsersActionsType.LOAD_USER_FAIL,
    props<{message: string}>(),
);
...

const allUserActions = union({
    ...
    LoadUserRequest,
    LoadUserSuccess,
    LoadUserFail,
...
});

export type UserActions = typeof allUserActions
```

user.reduser.ts

```
import { ActionReducerMap, createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";

import { UserDTO } from "src/app/interfaces/user.interface";
import * as userActions from "./user.actions";
import AppUserState from "./user.state";

export interface UserState {
    userDTO: UserDTO[],
    loadCouter: number,
    errorMessage: string,
};

const initialstate: UserState = {
    userDTO: [],
    loadCouter: 0,
    errorMessage: "",
};

export const userReduser = createReducer (
    initialstate,
    ...
    on(userActions.LoadUserRequest, (state, { userId }) => ({
        ...state,
    })),
    on(userActions.LoadUserSuccess, (state, { user }) => {
        const userCurrent = state.userDTO.filter(item => item.id === user.id);
        console.log(userCurrent)
        return {
            ...state,
            userDTO: userCurrent,
        }
    }),
    on(userActions.LoadUserFail, (state, action) => ({
        ...state,
        errorMessage: action.message,
    })),
    ...
);

export const reduserUser: ActionReducerMap<AppUserState> = {
    users: userReduser,
}
```

user.effects.ts

```
    loadUser$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() => this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType(userActions.UsersActionsType.LOAD_USER_REQUEST),
            switchMap((action: any) => this.userService.getUser(action.userId)
                .pipe(
                    map((user) => userActions.LoadUserSuccess({ user })),
                    tap((res) => console.log(res.user)),
                    catchError((error) => of(userActions.LoadUserFail(error)))
                )
            )
        ),
        { useEffectsErrorHandler: false }                
    );
```

user.selectors.ts

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from "@ngrx/store";

import { UserState } from "./user.reducer";

export const getUserFeatureSelector = createFeatureSelector<UserState>('users');

....
export const getUserSelector = (userId: number) => createSelector (
    getUserFeatureSelector,
    (state: UserState) => state.userDTO.find(user => user.id === userId),
);
...
```

user.state.ts

```
import { UserState } from "./user.reducer";

export default interface AppUserState {
    users: UserState,
}
```

Comment: Судя по коду, у вас данные берутся из `store`, уточните, что это за стор такой. Возможно тогда будет немного понятнее решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: Я добавил весь srore касаемый загрузки одного user по id. Проблема в следующем, effect каждый раз отрабатывает при перезагрузке, данные приходя о user, но ошибка в reduser поскольку он находит данные совпадения только при первой загрузке, при последующих перезагрузках undefeined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам спросил и сам решил, нужно просто в Effect проверить используя withLatestFrom есть ли users в store, близко даже об этом никто не сказал, теперь всё работает без ошибок в console.

```
    loadUser$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() => this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType(userActions.UsersActionsType.LOAD_USER_REQUEST),
            switchMap((action: any) => this.userService.getUser(action.userId)
                .pipe(
                    withLatestFrom(
                        this.store.select(getUsersSelector),
                    ),
                    map(([user, users]) => {
                        if (users) {
                            return (userActions.loadUserSuccess({ user }));
                        } else {
                            return { type: 'Empty Action' };
                        }
                    }),
                    catchError((error) => of(userActions.getFail(error)))
                )
            )
        ),
        { useEffectsErrorHandler: false }    
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Первое - стор наверняка пустой, поэтому юзера просто нет, поэтому undefined.

Второе - хорошо бы отписываться от селектора в `switchMap`, чтобы не получить утечку памяти и неожиданное поведение после нескольких заходов на детали и обратно. `take(1)` или `first()` с этим справится.

Третье, очень странное именование аргумента в первом `map` операторе. Туда попадает весь объект параметров, стоит его так же и назвать - `params`.

Comment: Yugofx, Перое: Как стор может быть пустым если при переходе с главной страницы на detail, user с детальной информацией загружается но когда вы перезагружаете приходит undefined. Получается первый раз стор отработал нормально второй раз нет??? Второе: Насколько я знаю switchMap автоматически отписывается от потока. Третье: Даже если я изменю userId на params результат будет тот же.

Comment: Николай, про switchMap еще гуглите, вы неправильно понимаете, как он работает. Про именование аргумента - ваше личное дело. Редюсер на LoadUserRequest бесполезный: лишний раз триггернутся селекторы стейта. Можно этот ивент вообще не обрабатывать. Еще момент: зачем хранить userDTO как массив, если вы всегда кладете туда один элемент при LoadUserSuccess?

Comment: Yugofx, UserDTO это всегда массив и там могут быть как все users для них есть свой метод LoadUsersSuccess, так и один user с методом LoadUserSuccess. Конечно можно в редусере завести отельные переменные для всех случаев, но на мой взгляд проще менять данный массив при update, delete, create и тд. Если вы говорите что редюсер на LoadUserRequest бесполезный, согласен, что тогда разу отправлять текущего user в LoadUserSuccess из компонента?